# Arduino Mega Wifi Shield Timeout Error

Tags: arduino-mega, wifi, shields

I got an Arduino Mega(not original) and also a Wifi shield, when ever I try to upload my code to it, I get this error:

```
Sketch uses 5504 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes.
Global variables use 704 bytes (8%) of dynamic memory, leaving 7488 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes.
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

Without the shield on it works perfectly, but as soon as I plug it in it stops working, I tried uploading the code without shield and placing the shield but this way the serial port didn't work.

The shield I bought is:
**ESP8266 ESP-12E UART WIFI Module Wireless Shield Converter For Arduino UNO Mega**
[image]

**Edit:**
If there is anything connected to the arduino it wont upload, it is not just the shield, I can't get my OLED to work either. Also tried using the shield on my UNO and I get the same result.

Comment: The error usually means that there is a basic comms problem between the board.  If the Mega works without the shield this implies that the shield is interfering with serial port 0.  I'm assuming that the "debug port" is linked to the ESP, is that correct?  Do the dip switches affect how the serial port is treated?

Comment: @CodeGorilla I tried changin the dip switch but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

via Google I found this helpful site which has an answer that might help.  It is not the same question as yours, but it explains what the dip switches are for

[How to connect Wi-Fi shield ESP-12E-ESP8266-UART-WIFI-Wireless-Shield with Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24919/how-to-connect-wi-fi-shield-esp-12e-esp8266-uart-wifi-wireless-shield-with-ardui)

It seems that *IF* you have what is pictured a 'shield' version of the board, as opposed to a 'shaild' version, then when you plug it in to an uno it will stop the uno working, because of the serial connection from the ESP on shield pins 0 and 1.  I don't know where these pins are going on your mega, but it might be the same issue.  This page recommends bending the pins out the way and wiring them to other pins - Which is at your risk.  You could trial it by wiring the whole shield to the mega and seeing if it worked.

https://claus.bloggt.es/2017/02/26/arduino-esp8266-wifi-shield-elecshop-ml-by-wangtongze-comparison/